# Create drive time isochrones in R

Tags: r, osrm

I am using OSRM to create drive time isochrones using this code

```
library(osrm)
library(osrmr)

s10.df<-structure(list(id = c(1010000273, 1010001028, 1010003635, 1010006693, 1010013430), 
           long_wgs = c(-1.564636192, -1.56677146, -1.554945908, -1.56773222, -1.564188582),
           lat_wgs = c(53.82838137, 53.82924493, 53.83130225, 53.82848279, 53.82857442)), 
           row.names = c(273L, 1023L, 3357L, 6326L, 12301L), class = "data.frame")

iso.list<-list()
for (i in 1:nrow(s10.df)){
  print(i)
  pt<-c(s10.df[i,]$long_wgs,s10.df[i,]$lat_wgs)
  iso.list[[i]] <- osrmIsochrone(loc = pt, breaks = 30)
}
length(iso.list)
iso<-do.call("rbind", iso.list)
```

However when I run the code it is inconsistent. Sometimes it will run for all 5 points, sometimes it will run for less than 5 with non-fatal errors (subsequent points may be calculated):

```
OSRM returned an error:
Error in if (res$code != "Ok") {: argument is of length zero
```

other times it will stop with a fatal error (no further points processed):

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘coordinates’ for signature ‘"NULL"’
```

If I can identify the OSRM returned error it's OK, I can just "re-submit" the point until I get a result. However with the Error in (function( ... results no further processing is possible.

I have seen suggestions elsewhere that I should set up a local OSRM server (on a Windows 10 PC?) but that appears to be an order of magnitude in further complications. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I believe that I have now set up a local osrm server to use in place of the demo server (see below). Looking at the osrmIsochrone R code if I can specify an option of "http://127.0.0.1:5000/" to the function I should be able to use my local server. But how in R to set the results of getOption("osrm.server") to be "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"? Thanks.

Comment: Set the new server with `options(osrm.server = "nameofserver")`

Comment: Thanks. I now have osrm querying my local server. Didn't think we'd be able to do this so quickly. This web site was useful https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Running-OSRM too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same results each time I run your code. However, some tips which may help.

Firstly, since you have two similar packages open, perhaps ensure there is no confusion between those packages by placing `osrm::` in front of any functions from that package, like so

```
iso.list[[i]] <- osrm::osrmIsochrone(loc = pt, breaks = 30)
```

Secondly, you can inspect a function by typing it into the console (without parenthesis or arguments). In the case of `osrm::osrmIsochrone`, there does not appear to be any randomness (some functions have some randomness, for example some machine learning functions). But just to be sure, try adding `set.seed(1234)` at the start of your script. It can't hurt to do this.

Comment: Thanks for trying the code and your suggestions. I believe that it is something to do with the OSRM server that the package is communicating with via an API. It is the results (or lack thereof) from the API that is generating one or other of the error messages. I have tried your suggestions and running the script on a home PC and a work PC and still see the "random" outcomes. Can anyone suggest a meaning behind each of the messages. Is there an alternative OSRM server that I can us? If so how to tell the package to use any alternative server?

Comment: @StephenClark interesting. The documentation [(here)](https://github.com/rCarto/osrm) says "You should be careful using the OSRM demo server, it is not always very stable". I wonder if for some reason it's using the demo server rather than the one on CRAN. Perhaps uninstall the package and  be sure the reinstall via `install.packages("osrm")`

Comment: Again, thanks. As you suggested I looked at the source code and this appears to be the server it is using. > getOption("osrm.server")
[1] "http://router.project-osrm.org/" . I am not sure what alternatives there are (other than setting up my own local server). Maybe you are more successful because you are in a "better" place for communicating with the server.

Comment: @StephenClark that's a possibility. I think that `"router.project-osrm.org/"` may be a demo server. So we should figure out how to tap into a production osrm server in order to get production (much more reliable) data, unless we can confirm that `"router.project-osrm.org/"` is, in fact, production